# What is the implication of "collateral and self-expression" in this passage?

Tags: meaning

> What started as a side interest has since budded into an enterprise generating over $1 million a year in annual revenue and satisfying a market demand for **collateral and self-expression**. It didn’t happen overnight, but it snowballed from the simple daily decision to do something she enjoyed.

What does *collateral and self-expression* mean?

Comment: Does "expression" mean "supplying" here?

Comment: I have found a synonym for expression:"social grace", is it possible that it means "social grace" here? If yes, what would be the meanings of "collateral" and "self" ?( foreign and domestic ,respectively)?

Comment: It would make sense if they had said "collateral _for_ self-expression". The buttons constitute an asset (collateral) which can be used _for_ self-expression.  Or, it could be referring to two different types of customers: businesses use them as "marketing collateral"; individuals for "self-expression". This would have been better said as "collateral _or_ self-expression."

Comment: "collateral" is simply a typo for something else ... perhaps "corporate gifts".

Comment: Hi Joe! Please take a look at the whole article in this link: http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/247170 ,                                      I don't know! Maybe you are right! :)

Comment: Thanks Barmer for edit :), but it was the original passage from this link: 

http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/247170

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was a market for people expressing themselves via buttons with slogans, pictures, and icons?  Who knew?  Not I, but apparently Christen, the owner of Busy Beaver Button Company did.  According to entrepreneur.com the company has $1M in annual revenue.  So "self-expression" means that BBB Co. satisfies a need for people to express themselves.

"Collateral" is a little harder to understand.  One meaning is the surety that a borrower puts up for a loan, but the market doesn't demand that.  Banks do.   A second meaning of "collateral" is something additional but of secondary consideration.  You will often hear this used as a military euphemism for killing civilians -- additional casualties that weren't intended but however unfortunate, are of importance secondary to the success of the mission.  So it's possible that "collateral and self-expression" means "collateral expression and self-expression" with "collateral expression" meaning that buttons with slogans are a means of making oneself understood in addition to the straightforward way of just speaking up.

Perhaps it's just the wrong word, but I can't think what would replace it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Deadrat! Nice explanation! But I am still looking for simple substitute for that phrase( collateral and self-expression). Like you, I understand the meaning as whole, but don't know what other terms can be used here! :)

Comment: "incidental and personal expression"

Answer (score 1):

Let us think in this way.For convenience's sake,imagine 'market' as customers. They demanded something in addition(may be, for social,cultural or physical need) They (the market) are in the look out for a mode of self expression
So,in its pursuits for some thing in addition and mode of self expression, the market finds its fulfilment  through her enterprise which is now generating huge annual revenue.

Comment: Good interpretation! +1  thanks dear Barid Baran! :) , so you think "expression" implies "need" ,here.

Comment: No,self expression is to lay bare one's innerself ie., through painting, drawing, singing and likes. The enterprise presents that opportunity tothem.